# Match everything until first slash, get numbers between 1º slash and dash

Tags: php, regex

I need to get only the numbers from a `URL` between the first `slash` of a `URL` and the immediate `dash` after those numbers.

**In other words**

If this is my URL: `http://galleries.video.com/39061-all_other-text`, I need a regex to get only the numbers `39061`

Comment: I might be wrong but regex cannot be used for filtering by itself. With regex you can verify if a given string matches the defined pattern. Maybe you need to give us more context.

Comment: What tool/environment? How far did you get? Please show your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_match to extract only numbers

```
<?php 
$string = 'http://galleries.video.com/39061-all_other-text';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches); 

//Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 39061 ) )
?>
```

You can explode `$string` to get only last part of URL